# Can't create records in SQLAlchemy due to One or more mappers failed to initialize

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a model file (simplified)

Repos have single user, and users can have multiple repos.

```
class Repo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "repos"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(512), unique=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="users")

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    repos = db.relationship("User", back_populates="repos")
```

When I try to insert a record I get the error:

> One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.  Original exception was: Mapper 'Mapper|User|users' has no property 'users'

How can I fix my model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`back_populates` for `user` relationship should be `repos`, and for `repos` relationship it should be `user`

```
class Repo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "repos"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(512), unique=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="repos")

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    repos = db.relationship("Repo", back_populates="user")
```